# Почему в докер контейнере запускает старый код?

Tags: php, docker

1. запускаю virtual box, монтирую папку с проектом, у проекта допустим единственный файл index.php с кодом echo "work!!!";
2. запускаю контейнер docker-compose up -d --build
3. открываю сайт в браузере по указанному мной порту и вижу test (код который добавлял пару дней назад в качестве эксперимента, exit("test"); )
4. захожу в контейнер и вывожу содержимое cat index.php, и с удивлением обнаруживаю только echo "work!!!";

ВОПРОС, откуда запускается старый код с test ?

Comment: Зачем выполнять п.1? Докер в п.2 сам всё это сделает. Может, кстати, и делает, монтируя другую папку. Что там у вас в docker-compose.yml?

Comment: version: '2'

services:

   application:
     build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile       
     ports:
        - 8000:80
     restart: always
     environment:
       DB_HOST: db:3306
       DB_PASS: 123
       DB_USER: user
       DB_NAME: test
     volumes:
      - ./misc/config/nginx/docker.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
      - .:/opt/code

Comment: В самом конце конфига `- .:/opt/code`. Не отсюда файл берётся? Не такой же путь монтируется в п.1?

Comment: да отсюда, а точнее code/public/index.php

Comment: 1. подождите я для virtualbox монтирую общую папку с проектом что бы иметь доступ для прямого редактирования, например /share/project/
2. мне для докера нужно также этот каталог указывать /share/project/ ?

Comment: Ну тогда а) удалите в своих шагах п.1 (докер это сделает сам) и б) проверьте что за файл у вас лежит в той папке откуда вы выполняете докер-билд - именно он потом попадает из локальной `./` в `/opt/code` на виртуалке.

Comment: `> я для virtualbox монтирую общую папку с проектом что бы иметь доступ для прямого редактирования` докер в инструкции `volumes` делает тоже самое :)

Comment: так пробовал я вытянуть проект из репо, без монтирования share/project
и от туда запустить docker-compose
все также, запускался контейнер, но при заходе из браузера вываливался старый код,
в самом скаченном проекте и в контейнере был новый код

Comment: Попробуйте открыть файл с уникальным именем, который раньше не открывали в папке проекта (создайте его, если такого файла нет). Если будет 404-я, то монтируется явно не то, чего вы ожидаете. Если файл откроется с актуальным содержимым, то поменяйте содержимое и обновите страницу. Если в этом случае увидите правки, то проблема где-то в самом проекте. Если не увидите, то это может быть кэш самой пыхи, например, в виде OPCache или ему подобного.

Comment: это сделать до запуска контейнера?

Comment: не имеет значения. он же в реальном времени подхватит содержимое примонтированной папки.

Comment: никакой реакции, на комментирования или добавления файлов, 
как то можно определить вообще контейнер работат при заходе на сайт или нет, хотя я пробовал порты менять, реакция на порты была((

Comment: Реакция не может быть "никакой. Вы либо видите 404-ю, либо содержимое вновь созданного файла.

Comment: ничего не меняется, даже если все файлы закоментировать, такое ощущение что правлю совершенно другие файлы

Comment: самое интересно что меняю конфиг nginx и никакой реакции
server {
    root /opt/code/public;
    index index.php;
    expires off;
    sendfile off;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте удалить композ вместе с дисками:

```
docker-compose down --volumes
```

а потом снова:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```